# Hide Date from Date Picker

Tags: android, datepicker

Currently I am using date picker native one but i want to change it in such a way that i only needed month and year 
how to modify this my code is following

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                     year, month,day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

    /*  year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;*/
        mynewYear=selectedYear;
        myNewMonth=selectedMonth;
        myNewDay=selectedDay;
        try {
            checkDate();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*time_date_TV.setText(new StringBuilder()
          .append(myNewMonth + 1).append("/")
          .append(myNewDay ).append("/").append(mynewYear));
               */





    }
};
```

I just want to hide date Section any help will be Thank full

Comment: Maybe this code sample helps : https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider/tree/develop/src/com/googlecode/android/widgets/DateSlider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Brain Storming half a day i have found this solution this may help other having such scenarios

My Custom class for date Picker is Following that will update the date in title every time user change month/year

```
class CustomDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog implements OnDateChangedListener {

private DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public CustomDatePickerDialog(Context context,int theme, OnDateSetListener callBack,
        int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    super(context, theme,callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context,theme,callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

    mDatePicker.getDatePicker().init(2013, 7, 16, this);

    updateTitle(year, monthOfYear);

}
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
        int month, int day) {
    updateTitle(year, month);
}
private void updateTitle(int year, int month) {
    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
//       mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        mDatePicker.setTitle(getFormat().format(mCalendar.getTime()));

}   

public DatePickerDialog getPicker(){

    return this.mDatePicker;
}
    /*
     * the format for dialog tile,and you can override this method
     */
public SimpleDateFormat getFormat(){
    return new SimpleDateFormat("MMM, yyyy");
};   
}
```

and the following is the code that will hide the day and its spinner from the date picker dialog

```
CustomDatePickerDialog dp = new CustomDatePickerDialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog,  datePickerListener, year, month, day);

               DatePickerDialog obj = dp.getPicker();
              try{
                         Field[] datePickerDialogFields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                         for (Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) { 
                             if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
                                 datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
                                 DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField.get(obj);
                                 Field datePickerFields[] = datePickerDialogField.getType().getDeclaredFields();
                                 for (Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                                    if ("mDayPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName()) || "mDaySpinner".equals(datePickerField
                                      .getName())) {
                                       datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                                       Object dayPicker = new Object();
                                       dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                                       ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                 }
                              }

                           }
                         }catch(Exception ex){
                         }
              obj.show();
```

Comment: Be very careful using this method.  You are effectively tying your code to specific implementation of the DatePickerDialog.  If in the next minor version Google changes its implementation (e.g. renames the variable `mDatePicker`), your code will break.  Moreover, if it works on stock google android, it doesn't mean that it will work on other devices, because different manufacturers often change things about in their implementation.  I found it the hard way when using a similar technique.

Comment: agreed with you will optimize it further

Comment: Agreed with Aleks G. He is absolutely right, this customization wont work for OS 5.0 or greater!!!

Answer (score 2):

Simply way - just to hide NumberPicker in datePickerDialog
here is code from my project

```
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        dialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);

        // hiding calendarview and daySpinner in datePicker
            dialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);

            LinearLayout pickerParentLayout = (LinearLayout) dialog.getDatePicker().getChildAt(0);

            LinearLayout pickerSpinnersHolder = (LinearLayout) pickerParentLayout.getChildAt(0);

            pickerSpinnersHolder.getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);


        dialog.setTitle("Pick a date");
        return dialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {

        Calendar result = Calendar.getInstance();

        result.set(Calendar.YEAR, yy);
        result.set(Calendar.MONDAY, mm);
        result.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dd);

        if (currentWeek != -1) {
            updateDateWeek(result.getTimeInMillis());
        } else {
            updateDate(result.getTimeInMillis());
        }
    }
}
```

to show picker just call

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
```

Comment: I would suggest pickerSpinnersHolder.findViewById(R.id.day).setVisibility(View.GONE); based on mDaySpinner = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.day); from android source code, because when your locate is US, this code hides the month spinner.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you.. if you are doing for only English.. also can be changes according to the requirements.

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.UK);
```

This will make date picker to appear in the form DD/MM/YYYY

Following code removes day spiner

```
LinearLayout pickerParentLayout =
(LinearLayout) mDatePicker.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout pickerSpinnersHolder = (LinearLayout) pickerParentLayout.getChildAt(0);
NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker) pickerSpinnersHolder.getChildAt(0);
picker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me after trying out several different approaches.

```
 datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date_picker);

 public void hideDay() {
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] f = datePicker.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (java.lang.reflect.Field field : f) {
            if (field.getName().equals("mDayPicker") || field.getName().equals("mDaySpinner")) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object dmPicker = new Object();
                dmPicker = field.get(datePicker);
                ((View) dmPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SecurityException e) {
        TLog.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        TLog.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        TLog.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified few things like:
Made style the android default Theme_Holo_Dialog and delete the day from the visibility.

Following few changes my code is:

```
pick_expire_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    CheckoutPaymentActivity.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            pick_expire_date.setText((monthOfYear + 1)+"/"+year);
                            mMonth = monthOfYear + 1;
                            mYear = year;
                        }
                    },
                    cyear, cmonth, cday);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("day","id","android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://learnlinky.com/2016/12/disable-day-selection-android-datepicker/

This worked for me :)

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = 
    new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK,
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, 
                              int year,
                              int monthOfYear, 
                              int dayOfMonth) { 
            txtMonth.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year); 
        }
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        ((ViewGroup)datePickerDialog.getDatePicker())
             .findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android"))
             .setVisibility(View.GONE);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK is deprecated